# How to deploy a SaS App created in Node as Backend and Angular as Frontend

Tags: angular, deployment, cloud

I have a cloud offering product, with 2 parts. One is Backend with Node and Mysql and other is frontend with Angular 7. My Plan is to go for cloud offering with this. Can anyone help with initial deployment and continual deployment.Flow will be like : Web app will be deployed on say abc.com. client will come to this domain and register themself. Once they confirm account, a new subdomain like client1.abc.com to be created on the same domain, i have to upload 2 app one for backend and one for frontend which are exact replica of the App which to be offered as cloud app. These uploaded app will be running on two different port and frontend app port will be mapped with the subdomain created for the client.

My Plan is to do it via script which will create a folder at defined location for every client and copy the cloud offering code in this. Will generate specific config file in this and via script only make both app frontend and backend up and live, and map this app with subdomain created.

Please help me understand if there is any better way of doing it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Show the deployment script you have made so far.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. First i want to understand if this is the right approach for cloud offering. second , my script just contain function to copy the boilerplate of frontend and backend app and pm2 start app.js to uplift backend app similar approach for frontend app.

Comment: It does not appear like you are using the SAS language for this app.  I have removed that tag.  Perhaps you meant SaaS? Software As A Service.